# How to plot $x^2$ over $-5<x<-1\cup1<x<5$

Tags: plotting, version-7

Is it possible to plot a function over a interval with a gap in the middle; e.g., $f(x)=x^2$ over $-5<x<-1\cup1<x<5$?

I am using Mathematica 7 and most of the options in the answers don't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In V8 and up, one can use [`ConditionalExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html):

```
Plot[ConditionalExpression[x^2, -5 < x < -1 || 1 < x < 5], {x, -5, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

*Response to updated question*

This might work in all versions of *Mathematica*:

```
Show[
 Plot[x^2, {x, -5, -1}],
 Plot[x^2, {x, 1, 5}],
 PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: `Piecewise[]` with `Indeterminate` as the default case works here as well.

Comment: @J.M. Nice to hear from you, again!

Comment: It's nice to be around again, for sure. :) I was ill for most of my hiatus...

Comment: @J.M. I'm sorry to hear that. I wish you better health in the coming year!

Answer (score 13):

You can also define f conditionally:

```
f[x_] := x^2 /; (-5 < x < -1 || 1 < x < 5)
```

Comment: This is good, but `f[x_ /; (-5 < x < -1 || 1 < x < 5)] := x^2` is better

Answer (score 12):

With

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[-5 < x < -1 || 1 < x < 5, x]
```

or

```
reg = Interval[{-5, -1}, {1, 5}]
```

do

```
Plot[x^2, {x} ∈ reg]
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

This might work for v7:

```
Plot[If[-5 < x < -1 || 1 < x < 5, x^2], {x, -5, 5}]
```

Comment: I am using Mathematica 7 and these options don't seem to work.

Comment: This is a nice V10+ solution to the problem: +50 just to draw attention to it for future users with an up-to-date *Mathematica*. `Plot[x^2, {x} ∈ Interval[{-5, -1}, {1, 5}]]` seems particularly nice to code.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for the kind words :)

Comment: Hmm, when I started the bounty, the least award on the popup menu was 100.  Well, I've seen +50 bounties, so I probably messed up somehow. But what the heck, think of it as a holiday bonus.  Don't spend it all in one place. :)  -- As I said, I like the fact that one just specifies the desired domain, and you don't have to define a new, temporary, auxiliary function or other such nonsense.

Answer (score 11):

Another way is with the option `RegionFunction`:

```
Plot[x^2, {x, -5, 5}, RegionFunction -> Function[x, -5 < x < -1 || 1 < x < 5]]
```

[image]

Comment: I guess this should work in V6 and higher.